# Change the input class when an image is selected (But not yet uploaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple image uploader (front end}

```
<input type="file" class="imgupload" name="file" />
```

But I made it with a padding and a background image inside a div with the overflow hidden
So the background image is visible but the form not, the form can still be used but it looks like an image

Is it possible to change the class when an image is selected, so that the background image can be changed?
If it is, how would could that be done?
If its not, is there another way to achieve something similar?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the class of the file input element, or of some container?  I'm guessing you are referring to a container, since you can't directly style a file input this way.  Also, are you only interested in changing the class when an image is selected, or when any file is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind it to a `change` event:

```
$("input[name=file]").change(function() {
    $(this).addClass("someClass");
});
```